# Printing time remaining of the Time.now class to the console

Tags: ruby

In the following:

```
x = Time.now + 300 #output - 2019-08-11 20:26:14 -0400
```

If this timer were to be counting down is there a way I could display the seconds remaining until it the time expires?

Example of what im attempting to do:

```
if thisIsTriggered
   puts "#{Time.secondsremaining} seconds until you can do this again"
```

Comment: Just subtract `Time.now` from `x`. The reverse of what you did to obtain `x`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For just seconds, it's easy:

```
end_time = Time.now + 200
puts "Time remaining: #{end_time - Time.now} seconds"
```

I don't think there's a method in the standard library to pretty format durations, so you need something like this:

```
def time_until(end_time)
  dt = end_time - Time.now

  dt_s = dt.to_i
  dt_m, dt_s = dt_s / 60, dt_s % 60
  dt_h, dt_m = dt_m / 60, dt_m % 60
  dt_d, dt_h = dt_h / 60, dt_h % 60

  parts = []
  parts << "%d days" % dt_d if dt_d > 0
  parts << "%d hours" % dt_h if dt_h > 0
  parts << "%d minutes" % dt_m if dt_m > 0
  parts << 'and' if !parts.empty? && dt_s > 0
  parts << "%d seconds" % dt_s

  "#{parts.join(' ')} remaining"
end
```

And the output:

```
irb(main):032:0> time_until(Time.now + 20)
=> "19 seconds remaining"
irb(main):028:0> time_until(Time.now + 2000)
=> "33 minutes and 19 seconds remaining"
irb(main):029:0> time_until(Time.now + 20000)
=> "5 hours 33 minutes and 19 seconds remaining"
irb(main):031:0> time_until(Time.now + 2000000)
=> "9 days 15 hours 33 minutes and 19 seconds remaining"
```